# Understanding $_REQUEST. Why is this not getting $_REQUEST['submit']?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

The below code is able to delete rows from the DB, but can't insert. Why is that?

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost","formuser","password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("formpractice") or die(mysql_error());


    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];

    // Add into DB Query
    $insert = "INSERT INTO Users(name, address) VALUES ('$name', '$address')";
    $insert_result = mysql_query($insert);

    // Delete from DB Query
    $delete = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE name = '$name' OR address = '$address'";
    $delete_result = mysql_query($delete);

    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
        if ($insert_result) {
            echo "Success";
        } else {
            echo "Failed to submit";
        }
        echo 'Submit Request'; 

    } else if (isset($_REQUEST['delete'])) {
        if ($delete_result) {
            echo "Deleted";
        } else {
            echo "Failed to submit";
        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: You delete the record that you insert lol

Comment: How are you loading this PHP code?  HTML form?  cURL?  AJAX?

Comment: You're aware that `mysql_query` runs the query, right?

Comment: @Sam: And probably a lot more records too :-P

Comment: check to make sure that your database user has delete permissions

Comment: I see. Still learning php. I was under the impression that the query is only called once I invoke the $variable that it's stored inside.

Comment: @iggy2012: No.  You don't "invoke" variables.  You read their values.  You "invoke" functions.  `$insert_result = mysql_query($insert);` this calls `mysql_query` and sets its return value to `$insert_result`.  When you do `if($insert_result)`, you're just reading the `$insert_result` variable, `mysql_query` has already completed.

Comment: you also seem to only be wanting to do something when a request var is passed, but you are always both inserting and deleting.. you might want to wrap your insert/delete in the if statements too..

Comment: Thanks @Zak. Coming from a javascript background, where everything is an object, I thought that this was the case.

Comment: @iggy2012: It doesn't work that way in JavaScript either.  Variables just store values.  Yes, those variables can be functions, but when you use `()`, you're calling the function and getting its return value.

Comment: @RocketHazmat IN JS, how about functions that don't have return values?

Comment: @iggy2012: They return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","formuser","password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("formpractice") or die(mysql_error());

$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
     // Add into DB Query
    $insert = "INSERT INTO Users(name, address) VALUES ('$name', '$address')";
    $insert_result = mysql_query($insert);
    if ($insert_result) {
        echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo "Failed to submit";
    }
    echo 'Submit Request'; 

} else if (isset($_REQUEST['delete'])) {
    // Delete from DB Query
    $delete = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE name = '$name' OR address = '$address'";
    $delete_result = mysql_query($delete);
    if ($delete_result) {
        echo "Deleted";
    } else {
        echo "Failed to submit";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I tried after learning that the query is called immediately. Would you have any suggestions about how I coded this up?

Comment: yes, 1) use pdo instead 2) make the insert and delete functions, 3) put your database config and load in a separate file/object 4) don't use global vars like $_REQUEST directly unless the page will stay this simple forever 5) don't mix echoing (view) code with your logic. Save your errors, messages, etc into variables, then echo them out later.